# form input name, two values

Tags: php, mysql

I am not sure if this has been asked before, here I go.
I have a form `<input name="name" value=<?php echo $myName; ?>`

The problem i am having is:

1. I am checking in the db if user exists, and if so here is what i do:

   $myName=$db->fields['name'];

so this name gets outputed here: `<input name="name" value=<?php echo $myName; ?>,`

however, when i submit my form, i also validate it, so if:

```
original name in db was: John,



new name after form submit is: John Adam.
```

But since I am outputing $myName, to the form, it is overriding it?
How do i use same variable name to echo to the input? in this case $myName, this below didn't do it!

```
if($db->recordCount>0)
{
$myName=$db->fields['name'];
}
else
{
$myName=$_POST['name'];
}
<input name="name" value="<?php echo $myName; ?>">
```

Comment: You should be doing the validation BEFORE the DB lookup.

Comment: ok how about retaining the form values even after validating to submit it to the db?

Comment: Just use `$_POST` when you want to access the form input values.

Comment: i am actually doing so, its the first thing on the top of my code, then i check to see if user exists, then i load the form. then afer submit, its validates to see if all the fields were completed, however, if user exists, the values are been override from the original db values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you just switch the order of your `if` statement?

```
$myName = '';
if (isset($_POST['name']) {
    $myName = $_POST['name'];
} else {
    $myName = $db->fields['name'];
}
...
<input name="name" value="<?php echo $myName; ?>">
```

It's hard to answer better without seeing the overall structure of your code, to see where the logic is going wrong.

Comment: hehe, i just did just that, and was going to comment on it:-) thanks Barmar!